# Angular Drop Down Pre Selected Value Shows up Twice

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have an issue where I have a pre selected value in a drop down showing  correctly but it is now showing up twice in the drop down list. Below is my code that supports this with expected vs actual results.

Controller:

```
this.values =[
  {
    "name": "A",
    "id": "123"
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "id": "456"
  },
  {
    "name": "C",
    "id": "789"
  }];
this.defaultValue = 'B';
this.selectedValue = _.find(this.values, value => {
    return value.name = this.defaultValue;
});
```

Template:

```
   <div>
          <select
            ng-model="vm.selectedValue"
            ng-options="choice.name for choice in vm.values">
         </select>
    </div>
```

Expected from dropdown:

Showing B as the selected value and when you open up the drop down you see

```
A 
B (with a check)
C
```

Actual: Showing B as the selected value and when you open up the drop down BUT when you open up the drop down you see

```
B (with a check)
A
B
C
```

As you can see in my current results B is showing up as the selected but then also again in the drop down. I only want B to show up once with it being selected. Any idea what I am doing wrong and how to achieve the desired results?

Comment: Try to use this: `<select [ng-model="selectedValue"><option [value]="choice.name" *ngFor="let choice of vm.values"></option></select>`

Comment: Are you mixing a jQuery library with AngularJS?

Comment: @OPV I'm a but confused with your snippet of code. there is an open bracket before ng-model that doesn't close and I do not believe [value] is proper syntax. Can you clarify?

Comment: @georgeawg no I am not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div>
          <select
            ng-model="vm.selectedValue"
            ng-options="choice.name for choice in vm.values track by choice.id">
         </select>
    </div>
```

make use of track by in ng-repeat

Comment: Switching this answer to correct because with this implementation plus undoing my mistake of using "=" instead of "==" I was able to get the expected results